# Visualforce Page as a PDF File with metadata

Tags: apex, metadata, pdf, rendering

Is there a way to render a Visualforce Page as a PDF File with metadata. Ex: Title , Authour, Subject and Keywords. I tried adding meta tags to the VF page and so many other ways. But non of them were unable to solve my issue.

[image]

*VF Page*

```
<apex:page controller="PDFExportController" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" renderAs="pdf" >    
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="metadata, keywords, test">
    <meta name="author" content="Bruno Lowagie">

</head>
<body>

    <!-- HTML to be rendered as PDF -->
</body>
```

*Controller*

```
public PDFExportController() {
    recordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 'inline; filename='+recordId+'.pdf');

    //Other methods

}
```

Comment: Can you share what have you tried already?

Comment: @tugce Thank you for your consideration. I updated the question.

Comment: I am interested too

Comment: Where in VF docs does it say it should work? Is Visual Force a must? You could open up your options by using third party JS libraries. Might be worth looking into PDF and LWC. There's some threads on jsPDF library for example.  Study the docs on the library and choose one, proof of concept that library... Repeat.  Also consider integrating with an app.